# log4net configuration transformation for different build configurations

Tags: configuration, windows-services, log4net, config-transformation

I am using Configuration Transform extension for use of different settings in Debug and Release build configurations of my Windows Service application. Here is my Release:

```
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender"/>
</root>
```

Here is my Debug, where I dont want to have SMTP appender, but it does not work (logged events are still send by SMTP):

```
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
</root>
```

Comment: I am not resolving publishing or release configuration, I am solving Debug configuration, when you debugging your application in VS. I dont want to get notification e-mails while debugging so I must have correct transformation statement to remove SmtpAppender.

Comment: Config file transforms when you click Build/Rebuild - modified .config file is automatically copied to either Bin\Debug or Bin\Release folder.  

I think you overlooked the fact, that it is Windows Service, not web application and I have this service modified in way, that it can be debugged like normal application. Config file transformation is not possible in any other project types than web application without using 3rd party tools. I just need to know how to exclude that SmtpAppender using transformation statement.

Comment: Are you declaring the XDT namespace?

Comment: Yes I have <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> in .config file.

Comment: Simple replacements like connection strings works fine. <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Here is debug connection string" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simplier than I thought:

```
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" xdt:Locator="Match(ref)" xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
</root>
```